# JQuery submit for rails form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

**The info:**

I have two models: `link` and `campaign` in show.html.erb for `link` I have the following two forms:

```
<%= form_for @link, method: :delete, remote: true, id: "delete" do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit :"Submit", id: "linksubmit" %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for :campaign, url: campaigns_path do |x| %>
    <%= x.hidden_field :title, value: @link.title %>
    <%= x.hidden_field :name, value: @link.name %>
    <%= x.hidden_field :link, value: @link.link %>
    <%= x.hidden_field :description, value: @link.description %>
    <%= x.hidden_field :owner, value: current_user.try(:email) %>
    <%= x.hidden_field :date, value: Date.today.to_s %>
    <%= x.submit :Start, id: "campaignsubmit" %>
<% end %>
```

When I click the submit buttons on their own, they do their job, which is either destroy the `link` or make a new `campaign` I need both to submit at the same time. I tried to do that with some JQuery. This is what I have.

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('button#campaignsubmit').click(function() {
        $('form#delete').submit();
    });

});
```

Doesn't work. I ran some tests, and I know the JQuery is functioning fine, just not with this function. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in this line `$('document').ready(function() {`. It should be `$(document).ready(function() {`. The binding is never getting called, so it won't bind, and thus won't work.

Edit: Side note... you can remove the tag names, since IDs are unique per page (or at least are supposed to be).

Comment: Not the problem... I had been running tests with .text() and divs to make sure the query was functioning properly, and it is. Something is wrong with the .click function.

Comment: It's not the problem! I ran other functions perfectly fine with 'document' Also, I tried running it with the fix, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Only other thing it might be is the `<%= x.submit :Start, id: "campaignsubmit" %>` produces an `<input type="submit">` instead of a button, and the binding fails because you're binding is looking for a button. Like I said, you can remove the tags `button` and `form` from your selectors.